# Css Hover Tooltip doesn't work in JqGrid

Tags: css, jqgrid

I have a css tooltip that I use to provide guidance, and I'm trying to include it in the jqgrid.

However, the title of the column appears on hover. The `<span>` does not. I tried adding `title:false`, but then nothing happens.

Here's the css I'm using:

```
.tooltip { border-bottom:1px dotted #000000; outline:none; text-decoration:none; cursor:help; }
.tooltip:hover em { padding: .2em 0 .6em 0; font-weight:bold; display:block; }
.tooltip { position:relative; }
.tooltip:hover span { position:absolute; left:1em; top:-4.5em; z-index:99; margin-left:0; width:150px; }
.tooltip:hover em { border:0; margin: -10px 0 0 -55px; float:left; position:absolute; }
.tooltip span { margin-left:-999em; position:absolute; }
```

And here's how it's applied:

```
    <a class='tooltip' href='#'>
<img alt='Help' src='/Images/question_mark_sm.png' />
<span class='tooltip_classic info'>Guidance Tag</span>
</a>
```

Not sure why it will work anywhere else but in the jqGrid. I've tried and tried, but it doesn't seem to work. (Well, the image shows up and the cursor changes, but no popup.)

Comment: You don't included and code which shows how you use `tooltip` class in jqGrid. Do you use custom formatter? Do you tried to increase the value of `z-index` (in CSS for `.tooltip:hover span`) to some value larger as 1000?

Comment: We would most likely need context for this. There is probably some other positioning or contextual CSS related to the jqGrid that is causing the tooltip to be hidden.

Comment: @Oleg, yes I have increased the` z-index` up to 9999, and it did nothing. I'm not using a custom formatter in the jqGrid column, I'm sending the html code I posted above as one of the column entries, so that shows up in the jqGrid. Just no tooltip.

Comment: @DoctorOreo: The problem is that you posted almost no information about the jqGrid. The demo with some element on the page which display the tooltip correctly and some grid which close to which you use and which reproduce the problem could help other who try helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove tooltip attribute from a jqGrid cell.

For me it works fine for all the browsers, except IE7. I used jqGrig gridComplete event.

**Here is an example:**

```
// _YourColID is you column name from colModel
$("td[aria-describedby*=_YourColID]", "#yourGridID tr").removeAttr("title");
$("td[aria-describedby*=_YourColID]", "#yourGridID tr").tooltip({

  // each trashcan image works as a trigger
  tip: '.tooltip',

  // custom positioning
  position: 'center right',                 

  // move tooltip a little bit to the right
  offset: [0, -10],                 

  // there is no delay when the mouse is moved away from the trigger
  delay: 0,                 
  predelay: 2000,                   
  onShow: function(e){
    if ($(e.target).parent("tr").attr('id') != -1) {
      yourTooltipFunction($(e.target).parent("tr").attr("id"));
    }
  }
}).dynamic({
  bottom: {
    direction: 'down',
    bounce: true
  }
});
```